# Desabilitar calendário no campo date do mobile

Tags: html5, css3

Estou desenvolvendo um site em HTML5 e gostara de saber se é possível desabilitar o calendário do campo date no mobile, obrigando o usuário a digitar.

Answer (score 1):

Completando. Para tirar a setinha que abre o Datapicker e Retirando as setinhas de ajuste "step by step" vc pode usar esse código.

Dentro do `@media` vc coloca o valor mínimo de tela para aplicar a regra do datapicker no input. Veja no exemplo:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 567px) {
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

Agora se vc apertar <kbd>Alt + Seta pra baixo</kbd> O calendário continua a abrir. Para corrigir isso vc teria que fazer um JS impedindo o usso das teclas.

Seria algo do tipo para evitar do usuário abrir o datapicker pelo teclado: *OBS: eu testei esse JS aqui, mas continuou abrindo... acho que precisa arrumar algo nele, mas fica a dica!*

```
dateInput.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyIdentifier == "Down") {
        event.preventDefault()
    }
}, false);
```

Aqui tem outros esclarecimentos e opções com jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270675/how-can-i-disable-the-new-chrome-html5-date-input

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer assim:

**CSS**

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
    display: none;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{ 
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

**Usando jQuery:**

```
jQuery('input[type="date"]').live('click', function(e) {e.preventDefault();}).datepicker();
```